# What's the Nodejs backend routine for "Register / Signin with Google"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using a Express Nodejs backend + React frontend set up and tried to implement a "Register / Signin with Google" function, but I do not understand what to store in the database after the user is authenticated. In the ordinary register with email approach, I send the email + password to the backend when I register and check if both the email & password match when the user login.

However, I don't know what to store in the db if one is registered with Google. I have already implement part of the google auth with google by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/authpack/easy-google-auth-with-node-js-99ac40b97f4c) in the frontend side, here's my code:

```
import * as queryString from 'query-string';

const stringifiedParams = queryString.stringify({
  client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/protected_home',
  scope: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
  ].join(' '), // space seperated string
  response_type: 'code',
  access_type: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent'
});

const googleLoginUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?${stringifiedParams}`;

return (
  <a href={googleLoginUrl}>Login with Google</a>
)
```

But then what's next? I've successfully pass through the auth process and redirected back to the `protected_home` page. But this only means that this user is a google user, what kind of information should I store their information in backend so that it indicated that the user has registered an account in my backend with this google account?

Also, is is possible to move the logic above to backend? Since google will redirect back to my `redirect_uri`like this `http://localhost:8000/protected_home?code=CODE_IS_HERE`, I need to browser to extract the information in `CODE_IS_HERE`. So it seems impossible to move the login logic to backend, any solution?

Comment: You can save email/mobile of user in db after getting the response from google auth service. this way you can make sure if user is already logged in if email exist in db. Further you can ask user to save password for this email. It all depends on what your buisness logic is, and what you want to do with this.

Comment: so the auth login will lay at the frontend?

Comment: I will not suggest this, auth login should be done on back-end, front-end should only provide need full data. The back-end should be responsible for this kind of things, doing login , saving related data and all that.

Comment: @Rohitpalod That's the question, I added some updates for better understanding. The auth information is embedded with the redirect_uri so it seems impossible to move the logic to backend because I need a browser to extract that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should not write it from scratch as there are libraries that deal with Oauth2: [PassportJS](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport), [openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client), [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant), [OAuth2-client-js](https://github.com/zalando-stups/oauth2-client-js). Those should handle all the below steps except storing actual details in your own database.

In general there are some basic steps when implementing third party oauth2 authentication:

1. Understand well how Oauth2 works https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
2. Redirect to your server from client (react)
3. Request authorization by redirecting to Google
4. Get authorization code which will be added to a url in a redirect from google back to your server
5. Exchange code for an access token (POST)
6. Use access token to get user profile details from Google (POST)
7. Save user details if they do not exist yet in your database - in theory you could skip this part
8. Create session/token and send it back to client (React) - it is another redirect.

You could also not store any user details on your server and just pass back the token obtained from Google to your React app (client), but then you'd need to check if it is valid on every request to your server. Which is why it is simpler to create your own session token and send it to the client.

There are more details as this is quite a topic to start with but RFC6749 should fill in the gaps.

Comment: #2 Redirect to your server from node app, redirect to server or redirect to a client side page?

Comment: Fixed, I meant to start the sequence it is from your client you need to redirect

Comment: Sry but I dont quite understand that part, #4 you mean the redirect_uri should be a backend url?

Comment: This flow is for server yes. This is what you were asking for, was it not?

Comment: I originally thought it is to redirect to a page at client side which act at the middle page that act at the bridge the auth and protected resources, then communicate with the backend at this page. As long as backend registration is done redirect user to the protected resources. But after reading your answer it seems everything (including the codes in my question) are placed in the backend. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Im not using any library becus im trying to understand the logic behind

Comment: You could get OAuth token purely in React (your client) but then it is useful only to get more details from Google. If you wanted to authenticate with that in your own server then something would need to verify it.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to save is user's unique id, his email or phone, and some other user data for your project.
This is just to know if the user already registered or to know the current user in backend.

From backend, you can just set a middleware to verify the token assigned from google.
Then you will get the user's id and you can find a user from your database, if exists, the user is authenticated.

1. Signin with google.
2. Get redirected with CODE
3. Send CODE to backend
4. Backend will get user id and email with the CODE using google api.
5. Save user and generate token.
6. Send the token back to your frontend.
7. Then the login or signup process is finished.

Comment: But for the frontend, the user is already redirected back to the `redirect_uri` immediately after he has passed though the auth process in Google's login page, looks like I can't make control of that. If according to what you said, I should be doing the verification in my db after user logins, and fire the redirect after verification is done (I insert some action in between Google and redirect).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, so...am I supposed to redirect user to a middle ui (`redirect_uri` page) to wait for 3 and 4, when 3 and 4 finishd then redirect user to protected ui page? I thought we should directly put the protected page in the `redirect_uri` page

Comment: sorry, i didn't read your question carefully.
So you can get CODE from redirect uri? 
On your protected page, You need to send the CODE to backend, the backend use it to get user id and email. You save these into your database and generate jwt token with user id and send it back to frontend.